# How to fold sub-vectors of an STL vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector

Given a numeric vector, how can I fold its consecutive sub-vectors into a single, smaller vector? Using STL algorithms, of course.

For example folding the vector {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} with a sub-vector size of 3 and a sum operation should give {1+4+7,2+5,3+6}

Comment: I'm not certain how you decided which elements should be summed.

Comment: According to sub-vector size=3

Comment: Does [this approach](https://gist.github.com/4139671) solve the problem? As written, it requires C++0x, but it surely can be rewritten not to.

Comment: @DCoder, I couldn't find documentation or headers for the `accumulate` overload you're using.

Comment: See the second overload at [gotapi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: In line 9 of your code the third parameter to accumulate should be of type T, not vector<T>.

Comment: No. `accumulate` walks over the input vector and adds each element to the current sum of the appropriate output vector element. If this code doesn't solve your problem, please be more specific about what doesn't work - does it compile, does it produce wrong output, ... ?

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there. I'm aiming for more concise code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.
Can be templated further to support operations other than addition.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> foldSubVectors(const std::vector<T>& v, unsigned int foldSize)
{
    std::vector<T> result (foldSize, 0);

    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i + foldSize <= v.size(); i += foldSize)
        std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), v.begin() + i,
                       result.begin(), std::plus<T>());
    if (i < v.size())
        std::transform(result.begin(), result.begin() + (v.size() - i),
                       result.begin() + i, result.begin(), std::plus<T>());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work with any STL implementation, since it involves dereferencing invalid iterators unless `v.size()` is an exact multiple of `foldsize`. It might not actually segfault or produce strange results in the case that `v.capacity()` is sufficiently large and the memory happens to be cleared, but a good set of unit tests should reveal the errors. As it's your question, I can't really comment on whether leaving out the incomplete tail is satisfactory, but it seems to not accord with the example in the original question.